# How to get leading 0 in seconds?

Tags: ruby, date

I'm trying to get hours, minutes and seconds from current time and print it into format "hourminutesecond". For example "121103". But there isn't printed leading zero when I try to do it with next code

```
irb(main):021:0> ct = Time.now
=> 2012-11-06 12:11:03 +0100
irb(main):022:0> "#{ct.hour}#{ct.min}#{ct.sec}"
=> 12113
```

Output is "12113" but I want "121103".

Is there method or option for that. I can extract it with regex but just wondering if there is easier way to do it.

Comment: The example is bad, but he is right, if the hour is 02:00:00 the result is not the one he expects

Comment: Ivan, please, fix the code in your question. It's misleading. There's no way `"#{ct.hour}#{ct.min}#{ct.sec}"` can return `3`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, you are right, I edited question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [time formatting](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime):

```
ct = Time.now
ct # => Tue Nov 06 15:31:03 +0400 2012
ct.strftime('%H%M%S') # => "153103"
```

Comment: That's it. Just shorter way to write it: `Time.now.strftime "%H%M%S"`.

Comment: @ИванБишевац: Sure, I just included intermediate steps for clarity :)

Answer (score 2):

You should accept Sergio's answer as that's the correct way to deal with date/time objects.

However if you must do it using String class you can use [rjust](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-rjust) method to add a leading zero.

```
"#{ct.hour}#{ct.min}#{ct.sec}" # 12113
"#{ct.hour}#{ct.min}#{String(ct.sec).rjust(2,"0")}" # 121103
```